# Windows 8 wifi problems with certain WAPs?

Tags: windows, networking, wifi

There seems to be a problem with Windows 8 wifi drivers working with specific WAPs. I have a Windows 8 ultrabook that works famously on my wifi network at home. When I take it to work (yeah we're BYOD) there are issues with connecting. A coworker of mine has the same problem. The Windows 8 laptops will only get a limited connection to the wireless network. Running the troubleshooter will "fix" the problem for about 3 minutes then the device is back to limited. The troubleshooter says "Not a valid IP configuration: fixed" and "no default gateway: fixed." Then you have full connection for 0 to 3 minutes before it goes back to limited. Bizarre (to me anyway). Right off I thought it would be a driver issue. I updated the drivers to the latest and greatest for the Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230. Didn't work. I uninstalled the Windows 8 driver then installed the Windows 7 driver for the device. That didn't work either (so I went back to the Windows 8 driver). I made sure the power management was correct, i.e., the laptop couldn't turn off the adapter to save on power. That didn't work either.

- at this point I think I should mention that, yes, all other laptops (windows 7 and XP) and wireless devices (iphones and win8 phones) connected and functioned perfectly on the wireless network*

What could be causing the intermittent issue? Especially since it's only Windows 8? I'm not sure why I went here, but I went into the settings for the WAP. Perhaps the firmware for this Netgear model didn't want to play nicely with Windows 8? It's possible given the age (a few years old Wireless-N 802T v2). I updated the firmware on the device. That didn't fix the issue. My frustration was quite high to say the least. So, I scoured the tech forums. Oddly enough, I did find something I hadn't tried that someone had tried which was changing the channel/frequency setting in the WAP from auto to, in his case, channel 6. That worked for him. I gave it a shot. Guess what? It worked for nearly an hour then the ultrabook just disconnected. It didn't even go to limited. It just disconnected. I changed to other channels only to find the same disappointment.

This doesn't happen on my home network. I talked with my coworker and she said the same about her home network. It is only at work with the Netgear WN802T v2 WAP.

Stupid things I tried that obviously didn't fix the issue:
Turning off the firewall
Disabling other network adapters besides the Intel Centrino
Resetting WinSock

Thoughts? Anyone?

Comment: You didn't mention the wireless AP platform, but I take it to be 802.11n based on the age you mentioned.  One odd thing I have seen reported by Win8 users with issues is to disable 802.11n on the router (or switch from WPA2 to WEP/WPA which has the same effect).  This isn't what I would call a "fix," but it would clearly point to a driver issue.  While Win8 wireless drivers have gotten much better, there still seem to be a fair number of issues.

Comment: Thanks YLearn I'll try that out and report back here on the results. I'll try going from 802.11n to b/g. I hate to change the work WAP from WPA2 to earlier, but I'll try it out just for the sake of documentation and reporting. I'll report back here after trying. Thanks for the suggestion! I appreciate it.

Comment: That did work YLearn. No, it didn't "fix" the actual problem, but that was a nice workaround. The speed was just too slow though 11 Mbps. I had a motorola WAP on the hardware shelf, added it and configured it to the network and, to no surprise, the Win 8 laptops connected quick, working just like they're supposed to. What I've concluded from this problem is the Win 8 wifi drivers just aren't playing nice with all WAPs. I wonder why?